# PHP Calendar with wrong start date for august 2015

Tags: php

I have got the above code from about.com. Everything works well except for the August 2015. The start date should be Saturday but the calendar shows Monday instead. Other months which I have checked so far are correct.

Any hint?

```
<?php
function calendar() {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $date = time(); // it was removed orginally.
    if (ISSET($_REQUEST['emonth'])&& ISSET($_REQUEST['eyear'])){
        $month = $_REQUEST['emonth'];
        $year = $_REQUEST['eyear'];
    } else {
    $month = date('m', $date);
    $year = date('Y', $date);
    }

    $first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);
    echo date('D', $first_day); 

    $title = date('F', $first_day);

    $day_of_week = date('D', $first_day);

    switch($day_of_week){
        case "Sun": $blank = 0; break;
        case "Mon": $blank = 1; break;
        case "Tue": $blank = 2; break;
        case "Wed": $blank = 3; break;
        case "Thu": $blank = 4; break;
        case "Fri": $blank = 5; break;
        case "Sar": $blank = 6; break;
    }

    $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);

        echo '<table class="event">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="7">'.$title.'-'.$year.'</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th>
                    </tr>';

    $day_count = 1;
    echo '<tr>';
    while ($blank > 0) {
        echo '<td></td>';
        $blank = $blank-1;
        $day_count++;
    }

    $day_num = 1;

    while ($day_num <= $days_in_month){
        echo "<td>$day_num</td>";
        $day_num++;
        $day_count++;

        if ($day_count > 7) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $day_count = 1;
            while ($day_count > 1 && $day_count <= 7) {
                echo '<td></td>';
                $day_count++;
            }
        }
    }

                echo '</tr>
                            </table>';
}

calendar();

?>
```

SOLVED

There was a typo of Sar instead of Sat in the switch case. Since it worked for most of the months I've checked, I overlooked it. It works now after correction.

Thanks guys

Comment: `$month = date('m', $date); $year = date('Y', $date);`.... where is `$date` defined?

Comment: Because there is a typo on the line `case "Sar": $blank = 6; break;`, it should be `case "Sat": $blank = 6; break;`.

Comment: @MarkBaker No where, that's why it's throwing an PHP Notice error. He should either define it or just remove it, to get "today's" month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining `$date` - although its not even necessary in your example.  The `date()` function will default to today if no second parameter is passed in.  (Also `isset` can take a comma separated list of variables to be cleaner)

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['emonth'],$_REQUEST['eyear'])){
    $month = $_REQUEST['emonth'];
    $year  = $_REQUEST['eyear'];
} else {        
    $month = date('m');
    $year  = date('Y');
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you have a typo in your switch statement that would prevent a match on 'Sat'.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For the $date, I intentionally removed it from the post since I didn't find it necessary. Since it worked for most of the months, so I overlooked the switch typo